# Search layout restapi returns fields for event or any custom object which don't have search layout configured. From where we are getting these fields?

Tags: rest-api, metadata, search-layout

Rest api for search layout **/services/data/v59.0/search/layout/?q=objectName** returns result for both event and task object. For both of these objects we can't configure search layouts in setup. How we are getting searchlayout for these objects in rest API if we can't configure it?

> /services/data/v59.0/search/layout/?q=event

> /services/data/v59.0/search/layout/?q=task

Same work for any custom object also. If a custom object don't have a tab created which is required for search layout configuration, we still get some result back from rest API. Where are these fields configured?

I checked these documentation of search layout API but there is no more information available. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_search_layouts.htm

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/dome_retrieve_search_layouts.htm

Is there a setting in fields or any other place where we can handle search layout fields returned here? My main concern is event and task object. For custom objects i can create tab and then we can set there search layout.

[image]